# I have been working here on basic calculator based on a formula in python

Tags: python, addition

```
def answers():
    ppv = tp/(tp + fp)
    rcl = tp/(tp + fn)
    return ppv, rcl


print("enter the value of true positive")
tp = input()
print("enter the value of false negative")
fn = input()
print("enter the value of false positive")
fp = input()
print("enter the value of true negative")
tn = input()
print('ppv and recall answers')
print(answers)
```

this is a basic calculator based on the formula in python and it doesn't show any error but also doest show the required output please check the below image for more info

[here check the output it returns something like this <function answers at 0x000002377567F040>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbxHt.png)

Comment: try `return f"{ppv} {rcl}"` or `return (ppv, rcl)`

Comment: it does not help, anyway thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (something like this):

- get the input from the user
- call the function and pass the arguments

```py
def answers(tp, fp, fn):
     ppv = tp / (tp + fp)
     rcl = tp / (tp + fn)
     return ppv, rcl
    
    
print("enter the value of true positive")
_tp = input()
print("enter the value of false negative")
_fn = input()
print("enter the value of false positive")
_fp = input()

print('ppv and recall answers')
print(answers(int(_tp), int(_fp), int(_fn)))
```

Comment: Glad I managed to help. You can accept the answer.

Comment: Can you correct your formatting? This will not be easy for a visitor to copy and try themselves. (Also you have a redundant print near the end).

Comment: @quamrana Not sure what needs to improved - you can try and modify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the function instead of calling it.

```
print(answers())
```

Instead of

```
print(answers)
```

It is also cleaner to pass the parameters to the function instead of setting and accessing them globally.

Comment: that doesn't help it shows an error I already it.        error is here                                                                        
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Padmanaban\PycharmProjects\presicionrecall\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(answers())
  File "C:\Users\Padmanaban\PycharmProjects\presicionrecall\main.py", line 3, in answers
    ppv = tp/(tp + fp)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Ah, for that you need to turn the output of input() into an int or a float. Try float(input("Enter the value of XYZ")) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your code. You should go through some basic tutorials in python which should show how to call functions and handle user input.

You don't call your function and you should convert your inputs to `int`s:

```py
def answers():
    ppv = tp/(tp + fp)
    rcl = tp/(tp + fn)
    return ppv, rcl


print("enter the value of true positive")
tp = int(input())
print("enter the value of false negative")
fn = int(input())
print("enter the value of false positive")
fp = int(input())
print("enter the value of true negative")
tn = int(input())
print('ppv and recall answers')
print(answers())
```

Maybe a better version would be to convert your numbers to `float`s and pass them as parameters:

```py
def answers(tp, fn, fp):
    ppv = tp/(tp + fp)
    rcl = tp/(tp + fn)
    return ppv, rcl


print("enter the value of true positive")
tp = float(input())
print("enter the value of false negative")
fn = float(input())
print("enter the value of false positive")
fp = float(input())
#print("enter the value of true negative")
#tn = float(input())
print('ppv and recall answers')
print(answers(tp, fn, fp))
```

Note that I have commented out the bit which asks for `tn` since it is not used in the `answers()` function.